# Pushing data with Windows Azure

Tags: android, design-patterns, azure, push-notification

I am currently using Windows Azure with Android and need to sync data between sets of users using PUSH notifications.

For example: User A uploads data to Azure which is stored in the SQL DB. That then needs to be pushed down to a specific set of devices and stored locally in SQLite.

What is the best design pattern for this? Should I be pushing the data with the PUSH notification or be using PUSH as a prompt for the app to then connect with azure and download the data.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think you would want to send a notification to the device that prompts the user to launch the app, and then the app fetches the data. I don't know how Android push services work, but I'd assume there is a fairly limited amount of data you can send in a single notification.

Comment: That's correct, there is a payload limit on a message of 4096 bytes.  If you're not sending very much data, you could do it in the push notification.  Otherwise, treat the notification as an indicator that your app should go to the server to fetch the data.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this is to use Windows Azure Mobile Services and the unoffical Android SDK.
The unofficial Android SDK can be found at: https://github.com/goldshtn/wams-android

The benefit of using Mobile Services in this case is that it's super easy to writer server-side scripts on INSERT. After you connect your project to a Mobile Service, you'd then head to the 'Data' tab, select the appropriate table, and then head to 'Script.'  Pick INSERT from the dropdown, then write a function that sends a push notification to the designated subset of users.  You'll need to write this in JavaScript.

There's some code you can work from included with the unofficial SDK, but if you check out https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-dotnet/#update-scripts you can get a sense for the steps you'd follow for an app on any platform (though the tutorials will only walk through Windows Phone 8, Windows Store, and iOS at the moment).